# Android Stock Browser Select Dropdowns Stop Working

Tags: android, html

I have an application that uses some regular HTML selects to get user information. Occasionally, when using it with Android stock browser, the selects will just stop working. When I click on them, the browser shows them receiving focus, but the options don't appear for me to select. Once this happens, it seems to break all selects that I access on that tab, even on other websites (including Amazon). If I open another tab, selects are working fine, so the problem seems to be limited to the one tab.

Has anyone experienced something similar, or is there perhaps a work-around that I'm not thinking of?

I could try replacing the selects with a custom control, but this would be a lot of work to do across all applications on my site, and I don't see it being that valuable for such a sporadic problem on one browser.

Comment: Same problem, did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: Not yet, we decided to ignore the bug, and QA hasn't brought it up in a while. Android Stock has too many weird issues to worry about every one of them.